# Product reviews in my sql database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, mysql

Apparently product reviews section within woocommerce does not have any option to adjust the amount of reviews displayed per page under screen options? Unlike the products section. Is there a way to mass delete reviews faster because at default settings I have to delete 5000 pages of reviews.

Also I have many reviews that have star ratings only but without any text comments or pictures. These are mixed within text reviews without images, is there any way to specifically filter out only reviews that have no comments with just star ratings so I can delete them bulk?

Ive found that I can access them via sql database, it allows for up to 500 per page display and sorting according to comment density or something as I can display entire long list of empty comment reviews, but because many reviews have photos with it, the sql database doesn’t display when reviews are photo attached or not, anyway around this?

Thx